# How do I use whiteColor in Swift and SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, swift

I'm running Yosemite and Xcode 6.  I created a new project using the "Game" option, SpriteKit and Swift.

In the override for didMoveToView() in GameScene.swift I added the following line to try to change the back ground color:

```
self.backgroundColor = SKColor(whiteColor)
```

This compiles but won't run, stopping with the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'whiteColor'"

The only import is:

```
import SpriteKit
```

Do I need another import to get whiteColor defined (which I assume is a constant in a header file somewhere ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+[SKColor whiteColor]` is a class method, so as usual, it translate to `SKColor.whiteColor()`

```
self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. this works.  Guess more reading, less typing for me !

Answer (score 5):

As you can see in the documentation, SKColor is just a wrapper.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define SKColor UIColor
#else
#define SKColor NSColor
#endif
```

That's why we use the usual way as Bryan describes.

Comment: and from swift playground `typealias SKColor = NSColor`